# How to get clear ram listener(event) on iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, caching, memory

Have possible get user press power key long time , then press home key until the screen change to home screen,

the iOS will clear the Cache(Ram).

Have any listener event can get the notify from iOS?

I need to get the cache clean event to do send last notify to user.

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  Not going to happen.

Pressing power for a long time is, effectively, the **ctrl-alt-delete** of the iOS world.  It doesn't "clear a cache", it reboots the device.

It is a non-maskable interrupt as far as your app is concerned and your app goes from running to not existing with nary a notice, signal, or, even, instruction to be processed.

Same goes for force quit.   Force quit does exactly that;  forces your app to quit regardless of state and with no notification.